# Rollback arangodb database to a specific point in time

Tags: database, arangodb, rocksdb, arangojs

I have (on purpose) truncated a collection in ArangoDB because I had to import a new data set into it.
Unfortunately the data I truncated was of use.

Is there a way to bring the database back to a specific point in time using journal files or something like that ?
I am using the `rocksdb` engine.
I can see in the `journals` folder of the database that there are `.db` files whose last modification date are 1~2 days ago.
There are also a bunch of log files in the `rocksdb` folder.

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: I'd love to see some good backup scripts that people have for ArangoDB to protect against this issue. It's not the question being asked here, but would have helped. With your server, did you have any virtualisation or snapshot mechanism under the covers that could have retained a previous copy of the database? Or maybe a backup?

Comment: I'm on AWS using EBS for storage, but no snapshot of the volume exists as I checked. The reason there was no backup in place is because this should not have been important data (it was a dev server), but unfortunately, it turned out to be.